# How to get the window position and update to other windows?

Tags: mfc, dialog

I have 2 dialog boxes in which I will display 1 dialogbox at a time..If I click NEXT in the first dialog box,I will hide the first dialog box and display the second dialog and vice versa...Now say If I move the dialog box after clicking NEXT in the first dialog..and when I click BACK(in the second dialog) ...it goes back to its previous position(to diaplay the first dialog box)..so I have decided to get the current window's position and update to the other window position so that it doesnt move even If I click next/back..I am not sure how to get the windows position and update to other..please help me if you guys know about this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an OnMove handler for WM_MOVE messages to detect when your window moves.  In the handler, you can either move the other window directly with MoveWindow, or you can send a private message to the window (something in the WM_APP range would be best) and let it move itself. Use GetWindowRect to get the width and height to pass to MoveWindow.

Comment: thanx for ur reply...an example/any reference would be great